# AngularJS: accessing attributes in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable of $scope.uses (I dumped it out below). From inside of "ng-repeat="(key, val) in uses", **I don't know to access the attributes in the repeat**. I am creating a page of tabs (one for each "crop"), each with a table of rows of expenses (I will need a nested ng-repeat once I figure how to access the attributes).

----UPDATE: this is my view:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
    <tabset>
    <!-- REPEAT FOR EACH CROP SELECTED-->
    <tab ng-repeat="(key, val) in uses" heading={{key|capitalize}}>
      <table class="table table-striped rowed">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left" style="width:20%;">&nbsp;</th>
          <th class="text-left" colspan="4">ACRE</th>
          <th class="text-left" colspan="4">
            {{key.acres|number:1}} ACRE TOTALS
          </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:10%;" class="text-right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">ARM</td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">
            {{loan.distributor}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">Other</td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">Total</td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">ARM</td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">
            {{loan.distributor}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">Other</td>
          <td class="text-center" style="width:10%;">Total</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-if="uses.expenses.length == 0">
          <td colspan="9">
            <strong>No expenses recorded.</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="c in x.expenses">
          <td>
            {{c.expense|capitalize}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.arm)">
            {{c.arm|flexCurrency:2}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.dist)">
            {{c.dist|flexCurrency:2}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.other)">
            {{c.other|flexCurrency:2}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.peracre)">
            {{c.peracre = c.arm * 1 + c.dist * 1 + c.other * 1|flexCurrency:2}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.calc_arm)">
            {{c.calc_arm|flexCurrency:0}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.calc_dist)">
            {{c.calc_dist|flexCurrency:0}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.calc_other)">
            {{c.calc_other|flexCurrency:0}}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-class="gtZero(c.calc_total)">
            {{c.calc_total|flexCurrency:0}}
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="success">
          <td>TOTAL</td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.acre_arm)>
            {{x.totals.acre_arm  | flexCurrency:2 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.acre_dist)>
            {{x.totals.acre_dist | flexCurrency:2 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.acre_other)>
            {{x.totals.acre_other | flexCurrency:2 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.acre_total)>
            {{x.totals.acre_loan | flexCurrency:2 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.loan_arm)>
            {{x.totals.arm | flexCurrency:0 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.loan_dist)>
            {{x.totals.dist | flexCurrency:0 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.loan_other)>
            {{x.totals.other | flexCurrency:0 }}
          </td>
          <td ng-class=gtZero(x.totals.loan_total)>
            {{x.totals.loan | flexCurrency:0 }}
          </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </tab>
    </tabset>
    </fieldset>
    <!--<pre>{{farmExpenses | json}}</pre>-->
    <pre>{{uses | json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

----END UPDATE

```
{
  "corn": [
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Fertilizer",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 164.97,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 164.97,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 57310.578,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 57310.578
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Seed",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 115,
      "peracre": 115,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 39951,
      "calc_total": 39951
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Fungicide",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 0,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 0
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Herbicide",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 32.94,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 32.94,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 11443.356,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 11443.356
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Insecticide",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 0,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 0
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Custom",
      "arm": 18,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 18,
      "calc_arm": 6253.2,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 6253.2
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Fuel",
      "arm": 40,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 40,
      "calc_arm": 13896,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 13896
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Labor",
      "arm": 20,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 20,
      "calc_arm": 6948,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 6948
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Repairs",
      "arm": 20,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 20,
      "calc_arm": 6948,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 6948
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Insurance",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 0,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 0
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Harvesting",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 0,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 0
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Misc Acre",
      "arm": 20,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 20,
      "calc_arm": 6948,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 6948
    },
    {
      "crop": "corn",
      "acres": 347.4,
      "expense": "Living Expenses",
      "arm": 60,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 60,
      "calc_arm": 20844,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 20844
    }
  ],
  "soybeans": [
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Fertilizer",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 26.5,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 26.5,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 15377.95,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 15377.95
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Seed",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 60,
      "peracre": 60,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 34818,
      "calc_total": 34818
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Fungicide",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 12.5,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 12.5,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 7253.75,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 7253.75
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Herbicide",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 20.06,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 20.06,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 11640.818,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 11640.818
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Insecticide",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 10.67,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 10.67,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 6191.801,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 6191.801
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Custom",
      "arm": 22,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 22,
      "calc_arm": 12766.6,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 12766.6
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Fuel",
      "arm": 30,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 30,
      "calc_arm": 17409,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 17409
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Labor",
      "arm": 20,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 20,
      "calc_arm": 11606,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 11606
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Repairs",
      "arm": 10,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 10,
      "calc_arm": 5803,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 5803
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Insurance",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 14.35,
      "peracre": 14.35,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 8327.305,
      "calc_total": 8327.305
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Harvesting",
      "arm": 0,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 0,
      "calc_arm": 0,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 0
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Misc Acre",
      "arm": 20,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 20,
      "calc_arm": 11606,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 11606
    },
    {
      "crop": "soybeans",
      "acres": 580.3,
      "expense": "Living Expenses",
      "arm": 43,
      "dist": 0,
      "other": 0,
      "peracre": 43,
      "calc_arm": 24952.9,
      "calc_dist": 0,
      "calc_other": 0,
      "calc_total": 24952.9
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share HTML code where you are trying to use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: added view code as requested

Comment: I am not able to see the code?

Comment: sorry, delayed because I had to format it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(key, val)` is used in repeaters for fill dropdowns that require value and name for example. For this scenario you need to do `ng-repeat="item in corn"` so you will be able to use the entire set of properties of each 'corn'.

If you have the array  corn inside the object *uses* then `ng-repeat="corn in uses.corn"`

I think you refers to properties when you say attributes.

Attributes are like this: `<corn crop="corn">` but when you do `{'corn':{ 'crop' : 'corn' }}` Crop is a property of the object *corn*